# Show legend of "Indicator plot" in dojo charts

Tags: charts, legend, dojo

Is there a way to create a Legend control for series that belong to Indicator Plot with Dojo Charting.

I've tried some standard well described ways from the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/gfx.html). But with no success! Legend are not appearing for Indicator Plot.

Maybe somebody know is it possible to draw legend for this case or not?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT(my code added):**
1. `id` - id of chart dom element.
2. `opts.chartOpts` - chart options from outside js.
3. `legname` - id of legend dom element.
4. `scale.avg` - is just a double value.

```
this.chart = new Chart(id, this.opts.chartOpts);

this.chart.addPlot("default", {
    animate: { duration: 1000, easing: easing.linear },
    type: ColumnsPlot,
    markers: true,
    gap: 1
});

this.chart.addPlot("avgline", {
    type: IndicatorPlot,
    vertical: false,
    lineStroke: { color: "#00ff00", style: "ShortDash" },
    stroke: { width: '1.2px' },
    fill: '#eeeeee',
    font: 'normal normal normal 11px Arial',
    labels: 'none',
    offset: { x: 32, y: 4 },
    values: [scale.avg],
    precision: this.opts.precision
});

//Add axis code goes here... cutted for clearance

this.chart.addSeries('Power', chartOptions.data);

this.chart.addSeries('Average', [scale.avg], { plot: 'avgline' });

var tip = new Tooltip(this.chart, "default", { 'class' : 'kaboom' });
var mag = new Magnify(this.chart, "default");
var hightlight = new Highlight(this.chart, "default");

this.chart.render();

this.leg = new Legend({ chart: this.chart, horizontal: false }, this.legName);
```

And as result of this code I see legend for 'default' plot 'Power' series only. And nothing for 'Average' series.

Comment: Please post what you tried. Alternatively, look at this example : http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_threshold.html

Comment: Thank for your comment, @Philippe! I've seen this example before but it not helpful in my case. I've edited my post with things that i have tried.